# Is there a solution to radio interference?

Tags: air-traffic-control, radio-communications, radio, lost-communications

I was reading about the Tenerife Disaster and came across what seemed to be the  probable cause behind the accident.

> A simultaneous radio call from the Pan Am crew **caused mutual interference on the radio frequency**, which was audible in the KLM cockpit as a three-second-long whistling sound (or heterodyne). This caused the KLM crew to miss the crucial latter portion of the tower's response. The Pan Am crew's transmission was "We're still taxiing down the runway, the Clipper 1736!". This message was also blocked by the interference and inaudible to the KLM crew. Either message, if heard in the KLM cockpit, **would have alerted the crew to the situation and given them time to abort the takeoff attempt**.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tenerife_airport_disaster

I understand that the science behind radio waves is the cause for this interference, but is there a solution (non-radio if need be) for when ATC and other aircraft talk over each other?

edit1: By solution I mean a way of only allowing 1 party to speak on a specific frequency at a time , be it technical or not. I would just want the possibility of pilots/ATCs talking over each other to be close to 0.

edit2: I know the Tenerife disaster was caused primarily by the pilot's inability to wait for clearance, and then report it back, but this question is about radio interference and if a solution exists, not if fixing radio interference is a worthwhile task to begin with.

Comment: What kind of solution do you mean?

Comment: @fooot, By solution I mean a way of only allowing 1 party to speak on a specific frequency at a time , be it technical or not. I would just want the possibility of pilots/ATCs talking over each other and not being able to hear to be close to 0.

Comment: Okay, "A" and "B" both go to key their respective microphones at the same time.  What do you envision should happen?

Comment: @RalphJ, Maybe a way of preventing A and B from ever dispatching at the same time in the first place (similar to a semaphore in software)? I just want to know why there is not a solution for this problem that has cost many lives.

Comment: @mins, Why is it considered not usually a problem? Even when some of the biggest disasters could have been prevented if talkover was not a thing?

Comment: @mins, I have found that these standards were increased greatly after this incident. I am still wondering if there lies a technical solution.

Comment: The problem was caused by the fact that VHF communications use amplitude modulation, the carrier wave is not suppressed unlike in single side band modulation. When there are two or more transmitters operating at the same time,  this will yield a strong interference tone that has as its frequency the difference between the frequencies of the two transmitters (they are never exactly the same, so, 200 hertz off means a 200 hertz tone). HF communications use single side band modulation where there is no carrier wave, this allows for multiple planes to talk simultaneously.

Comment: VTR. This question is perfectly answerable by talking about means of communication in operational aviation. Explain simplex radio, explain CPDLC, and explain why new equipment in a global industry can't just be implemented from one day to the next.

Comment: @J.Hougaard: As it is now, the question is only about interferences between voice transmissions and existing solutions. I voted to close it as it is a broad topic that doesn't fit the site principle of "a best answer" can be determined. Many solutions exist in the data/voice domain, including operational procedures.

Comment: @mins, In my opinion, this question may not seem to have a "best answer" because the problem itself is not being actively solved by todays aviators. They don't need to solve it, because it isn't a problem at all if humans stay alert and stick to protocol. That makes it seem like this question doesn't even need to be answered, but if this topic were to become a bigger priority, I am confident that a solution similar to J. Hougaard's would be looked into.

Comment: @mins, Not sure what you are getting at, but it is not my opinion that radio interference was part of the Tenerife accident...There is no way around it. At first, my question did seem to fall along the lines of "radio interference caused this great disaster, why isnt it fixed?!?!?", but after seeing that it is never the primary cause, I ammended my question to better suit the idea of a theoretical solution.

Comment: It's obviously possible to eliminate this sort of interference, since cell phone systems do it.  (You can hold e.g. conference calls with no problem.)  The real problem would be in getting everyone to change out their equipment.

Comment: @jamesqf: Correct, these techniques are not new. 4G uplink (phone to base) uses ["single-carrier FDMA"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-carrier_FDMA), an implementation of the principle known as "direct-sequence spread spectrum" ([DSSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct-sequence_spread_spectrum)), which combines multiple access to a single frequency and efficient use of the medium. This is similar to a WiFi -n channel, or multiple video programs on cable or optical fiber and GNSS. Notice that this is relevant for digitalized signals only.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Firstly, it is worth noting that the blocked radio transmission is only one point on a very long list of factors that caused the horrible accident on Tenerife. There is enough redundancy in aviation systems and procedures that a single fault somewhere in the system will [almost] never be enough to cause an accident. Weather, stress, a terrorist attack, company policy, poor CRM and many other things were also contributing factors.

Communication between air traffic control (ATC) and pilots is mostly based on simplex radio. Simplex radio only allows one station per channel to transmit at the same time; if two stations transmit at the same time, the signal will be blocked. Sometimes, if one signal is stronger, it will be possible to hear that signal but not the other. The main problem is that the two stations transmitting will have no way of knowing that they are blocking eachother. This limitation regularily results in various incidents - for example, when there are two aircraft with similar sounding radio callsigns on an ATC channel, one crew might mistake an instruction for the other flight, thinking it is actually meant for them. If both flights read back the instruction at the same time, neither of them will hear the readback from the other aircraft and realise the mistake, and ATC might hear just one of the readbacks, and not realise that both flights are following the instruction meant for just one of them.

So why isn't there work being done to phase out simplex radio in aviation?

**There is.** It's called CPDLC, or Controller-Pilot Datalink Communications. (Other, similar systems exist as well, with different names. In the following I will just discuss CPDLC).

[image]

CPDLC is a digital system that allows ATC and pilots to communicate via *text*. It is already widely deployed in many areas, one example being Maastricht UAC, one of the busiest area control centres in Europe. Multiple stations can transmit at the same time, without the risk of blocking other transmissions.

So why do we still have simplex radio?

So far, CPDLC is only used for area control. In areas where ATC instructions are time critical, such as an approach or aerodrome environment, we still rely on simplex radio, because it is guarenteed to be instantaneous - and pilots are used to acting immediately to a voice instruction. However, it should only be a matter of change of procedures and appropriate training before CPDLC can be used in all phases of flight.

More importantly, aircraft equipment is expensive. Replacing a simplex radio with CPDLC equipment involves a significant cost per aircraft. While this may be feasible for large airlines, remember that they only make up a part of flights. There are thousands and thousands of private planes, balloons, gliders and whatnot, and private pilots or flying clubs may simply not have the funds to implement CPDLC. And obviously, ATC can't turn off their simplex radio until **everyone** has equipment to replace it.

Another disadvantage of CPDLC, or other communication equipment that allows direct communication between cockpit and controller working position, is that it reduces situational awareness. A big advantage with simplex radio is that everyone has to listen to what everyone else is saying, since you can't talk when someone else is talking. This gives pilots the possibility to establish a mental picture of the traffic around them, which ultimately increases safety. As we saw with Tenerife, the lack of such a mental picture can result in tragic outcomes. However, simplex radio has probably prevented many other accidents, because everyone on the frequency knew what was going on around them. The [Providence incident of December 1999](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qUDFY5qlTSA) comes to mind as one example among many.

So, is there a solution to radio interference? Yes, there is. Is it easy to implement? No, it is both technically and financially difficult. Will it necessarily prevent accidents such as the one on Tenerife? No; a thorough safety and risk analysis must be carried out before deploying it everywhere.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. It seems that this technology could be simplified even more to something that even can work alongside traditional radio technology. Maybe something that would read the pilots/ATC calls and voice translate them to text, then send them out to others on that frequency.  Being able to have a somewhat accurate text log that one could look back on seems very plausible to me. Definitely not with the current state of antiquated private aviation, but maybe sometime in the distant future.

Comment: Even better, once you have digital data link, glass cockpit, and computerized ATC, in theory it should be possible for the display to show the surface radar view that ground controllers sees, and for these display to be annotated with all aircraft's clearance statuses. Much easier to digest than radio comms even with proper phraseology,  far better situational awareness, and the radio would be reserved to relaying non standard information (e.g. debris, aircrafts not showing correctly in radar).

Comment: In my experience, airlines are not apt to spend money on avionics upgrades. I'm not saying they don't, but the most likely response is, "We're retiring those planes in five years, so we're not going to spend that kind of money." The GA fleet is hard pressed to require as well because, money. This one issue is (IMHO) the biggest obstacle in aviation equipment modernization.

Answer (score 6):

This isn't really an answer, but it got to be far too long to put in the comments...

Two paragraphs later in the same Wiki:

> After the KLM plane had started its takeoff roll, the tower instructed the Pan Am crew to "report when runway clear." The Pan Am crew replied: "OK, we'll report when we're clear." *On hearing this*, the KLM flight engineer expressed his concern about the Pan Am not being clear of the runway by asking the pilots in his own cockpit, "Is he not clear, that Pan American?" Veldhuyzen van Zanten emphatically replied "Oh, yes" and continued with the takeoff".
> <sub>-Wikipedia, emphasis mine</sub>

Not that a technology solution wouldn't be good, but this is the accident that really drove the development and adoption of [CRM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crew_resource_management) and standardization of radio phraseology, which, had it been in place at the time, may have had a very strong chance of preventing the incident in the first place.

There were so many factors leading to this particular accident that the interference was only one issue. While it was *very* important, it wasn't the final bit of communication, wasn't the last thing that was said, and wasn't the last opportunity for the KLM flight to abort takeoff.

Comment: Learning that the standards were raised after this incident seems like solution enough for me. I will mark as answer if no better ones show up soon, thank you.

Comment: Thanks. Waiting a day or two for a better answer is definitely a good idea!

Comment: Also, nearly every accident, especially the fatal ones, drives some sort of improvement in the airline industry.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this is possible with technology, but there is a big problem too. How do you decide which radio has priority?

Right now the system is "whoever has the strongest signal, wins", but both will probably hear a squeal. ATC may hear both, but the strongest one will probably be audible over the noise. This can be advantageous for example if an aircraft in the pattern needs to declare an emergency while ATC is talking to somebody on long final.

The current system, while antiquated, does work for the most part. There are very few examples of accidents caused by missed communication due to being stepped on by another aircraft. Usually there is more to it, for example in the Tenerife accident the pilot was anxious to get going and ignored the flight engineer's warning about the Pan Am aircraft not being clear. As Freeman pointed out this is where CRM broke down, not the radio's. The other contributing factor in this accident was ATC's inability to monitor the traffic on the ground because of fog and no ground radar.

In the United States there is an [active push to reduce commercial radio traffic by using in-cockpit displays to relay ATC instructions](https://www.faa.gov/nextgen/programs/datacomm/). This system relies both on the new ADS-B mandate being in place as well as regulations for equipment being installed in aircraft that can display and alert pilots.

Comment: I think the last paragraph is the key to this. It reduces the radio chatter and incorrect readbacks, but it also allows for absolute confirmation as to whether you have clearance or not.

Comment: @TomMcW My audio panel also has a "playback" button that can play back the last 3 transmissions. I'm not sure how well it works in really busy airspace since it doesn't distinguish messages meant for you or just chatter on the frequency.

Comment: That heterodyne squeal provides an indication to everyone on the frequency that someone was stepping on someone else.  The response to the squeal should be "Say again".

Comment: @Gerry:  Radio reception is not always symmetric:  When two receivers are located in different places, one may hear a conflict and squeal, while the other may receive just one transmitter.  Just because one radio picks up a "step-on", does not mean that another radio will.

Comment: @abelenky, but the stations that didn't pick up a "step-on" missed at least one of the transmissions and therefore it is still appropriate to request a repeat.

Answer (score 3):

It's worth noting that any solution to the question you raised would not have prevented this, or similar disasters, from happening.

Regardless of any missed or corrupted transmissions with two people speaking at the same time, the crew commenced the take-off without having received, and [read-back](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procedure_word#Read_back_for_check), a clearance to do so.  Short of replacing humans entirely with computers, there is no solution to a pilot ignoring the established and regulated procedures, put in place to avoid **exactly** this problem.

The procedures also include the phrase "say again" if you did not hear clearly and simply asking if you have clearance if you have not positively received and understood it.

This disaster was caused by crew error driven by "[gethomeitis](https://www.bea.aero/etudes/gethomeitis/gethomeitis.htm)" and not any problem inherent with radio communications.

Comment: I know the Tenerife disaster was caused primarily by the pilot's inability to wait for clearance, and then report it back, but this question is about radio interference and if a solution exists, not if fixing radio interference is a worthwhile task to begin with. Thank you for the "get-home-itis" link, very useful! I have edited my question to remove "Why", as you and others have proven to me it is very very rarely the primary cause of an accident.

Comment: I would say not rarely, but never. The primary cause of an incident such as this is human failure. Lost or garbled comms can only ever be a contributing or secondary factor. You could fix the problem you ask about, at great expense and introducing something else to go wrong, and have exactly the same outcome for a new problem (radio failed, crew didn't know), misunderstood since English not first language and so on. Make something idiot proof and someone will just invent a better idiot. The procedure of positive clearance and readback catches them all. Without it, you do not enter the runway.

Comment: I agree that proper positive clearance and readback catches all. Sadly, that is not how the real world works, and humans succumb to laziness, fatigue, and other things which cause breakdowns in the procedure. That is why at least to me, it is important to explore any and all possible improvements in regards to the entire overlying system.

Comment: It's called Human Factors. Breakdown of proper procedure should not be punishable by death.

Answer (score 2):

There are new ATC radios that have "Detection of Simultaneous Transmissions" or DsiT that alert the controller that more than one aircraft is transmitting.  R&S's Series4200 is one of them.  The controller will get a visual alert on the voice communication system display.

Comment: Not that the horrible sound in their ears *doesn't* alert the controller already...

Comment: @UnrecognizedFallingObject: I think in most cases what's needed would be an indication *for the person transmitting* that their signal is likely not being received.  An automated system that would detect probable signal stomping and transmit a warning signal on a channel reserved for that purpose, along with receivers that would monitor that channel and alert if a signal was received on it related to a current transmission would seem like a simple remedy which should not affect compatibility with existing equipment.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this exists in aviation radios, and it would not help if both operators keyed at precisely the same time, but on many amateur radio transceivers (even $35 Baofengs), there is a feature called "busy channel lockout" (BCLO) or something similar. If someone keys their radio, and you try to key up right after they do (not realizing that they have keyed), your radio will refuse to transmit. This prevents accidental interference with another station. However, if a station with BCLO keys first and a station without it keys afterward, the interference will still occur; everyone on the channel has to have BCLO supported and enabled for it to work optimally.

BCLO has a few advantages over DSiT. It is much simpler; it only has to detect a single signal (already done by squelch), not determine how many signals there are. It also prevents interference, rather than just detecting it.

Basically, DSiT does this, when a signal is received:

```
if moreThanOneSignal() { // complicated (expensive!)
    turnLightOn() // interference still happens, ATC just knows about it
}
```

While BCLO does this, when the pilot keys the mic:

```
if atLeastOneSignal() { // very simple, already done as part of squelch circuit
    dontTransmit() // interference is avoided completely; the first station to transmit is heard
}
```

Comment: This (well, effectively the same thing) was already mentioned [5 years ago](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/39115/5517).

Comment: @FreeMan DsiT tells ATC that two aircraft are transmitting. BCLO prevents the airplane's radios from keying if someone is already transmitting. DsiT detects interference; BCLO prevents it.

Comment: BCLO also has the advantage that it is simpler and therefore probably cheaper; it only has to determine if there is already one signal or more (already determined by squelch), whereas DsiT has to analyze the signal to see if there is more than one.