# Why is VHF still used?

Tags: radio-communications

I have a rather easy(?) question. Why is VHF radio still the main communication method between the ATC and pilot?
Is it because there is no better solution at the moment?

Best regards

Comment: "If it isn't broke, don't fix it"

Comment: Just to note VHF is simply a frequency band - it can, and does, contain digital data. Additionally, UHF is also used for aviation purposes. I presume you're asking why aviation used AM radio, rather than VHF specifically

Answer (score 3):

The reason radios in general are used is covered in this question [Why is radio communication still used?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/43022/why-is-radio-communication-still-used)

As for why VHF is the band of choice its largely because its assigned for aviation use and the the radio spectrum is not unlimited. Here in the US the FCC regulates which bands are for what, [you can find the full list here](https://transition.fcc.gov/oet/spectrum/table/fcctable.pdf) and you will see that many of them are in use for lots of different things so using a higher (or lower) band for aviation may not be possible as they are likely used for something else.